# Disable an outputlink coming from database based on condition

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing an app where I have come across at the condition where I am fetching some links from database, based on those links more retrieval is being done. I want to disable the outputlink if there is an empty row retrieved based on this outputlink.

I am swtting preRequisiteNull with boolean result and rendering the outputlink in primefaces but it disappear when if only one row have true value.

My Code:

```
for(LabOrdersDTO laborderDto:labOrdersDTOListDataModel.getWrappedData())
{
    System.out.println("Speciman Name"+laborderDto.getTest());

    System.out.println(laborderDto.getLabNo());

    for(LabOrdersDTO laborderDto2:labTestPreReqList.getWrappedData())
    {
        System.out.println("Lab test"+laborderDto2.getTest());
        if(laborderDto2.getTestPreReq()!=null){

            preRequisiteNull = false;
        }else{
            preRequisiteNull = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is or what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, then your mistake is in your for-loops.

you want to disable link if one link = null ? right?

if yes then you have to breake the loop if one link is null, otherwise the next notNull link will override the value.

**replace this**:

```
for(LabOrdersDTO laborderDto:labOrdersDTOListDataModel.getWrappedData())
{

    for(LabOrdersDTO laborderDto2:labTestPreReqList.getWrappedData())
    {
       if(laborderDto2.getTestPreReq()!=null){

            preRequisiteNull = false;
        }else{
            preRequisiteNull = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**width this :**

```
for(LabOrdersDTO laborderDto:labOrdersDTOListDataModel.getWrappedData())
    {

        for(LabOrdersDTO laborderDto2:labTestPreReqList.getWrappedData())
        {
            if(laborderDto2.getTestPreReq()==null){        
                preRequisiteNull = true;
                // update the link state or no idea how you manage it to disable the link
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**BUT** i cannot see how you set the link state to be disabled. my suggestion will break if one row is empty, but you have to update the state of that link!